# Remove white space and sticky div edges?

Tags: html, css

Unnecessary white space is added to my nested divs in between .boxwrap and .lsmlbox + .rsmlbox which is making it impossible to line up .smlbox + .rsmlbox with .box
I believe this is a much more difficult problem to solve than expected?

I would like for the "inner" (referring to center of screen) margins of .lsmlbox and .rsmlbox to be dependent on screen size, but I would like the outer borders to always remain "sticky" to .boxwrap so that when the screen size changes the boxes only get narrower but remain lined up to the full sized .box div above it.

```
.box
{
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-bottom:80px;
}

.boxheader
{
font-size:17pt;
letter-spacing:3px;
padding-bottom:10px;
text-transform:capitalize;
}

.boxcontent
{
text-align:left;
border: 1px dotted #000000;
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
letter-spacing:3px;
}


.boxwrap
{
margin:0 5%;
}

.lsmlbox
{
display:inline-block;
max-width: 30%;
margin-bottom:80px;
margin-right:4%;
vertical-align:top;
}

.rsmlbox
{
display:inline-block;
max-width:30%;
margin-bottom:80px;
margin-left:4%;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="boxheader">SLDKFJSDLFKJSDLKJF.</div>
<div class="boxcontent">
SDFSDFLSDFSDFLKJ
</div>
</div></div>

<div class="boxwrap">
<div class="lsmlbox">
<div class="boxheader">Meet the Owner</div>
<div class="boxcontent">SDFSDFSDF</div></div>

<div class="rsmlbox">
<div class="boxheader">Your Best Source Since 1977</div>
<div class="boxcontent">
SDFSDFSDFSDFSDF
</div></div>
</div>
```

Edit: got rid of floating divs but now I'm in a deeper problem.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on what you want it for, but you could use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

on each item you want on the same line

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In some cases float is good.

In some - inline-block. I personally like inline-block.

You can read more about it here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

http://jsbin.com/qikubuce/1/edit?html,css - sample

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `position:absolute;`. For your case just remove the `float` in both `.lsmlbox` and `.rsmlbox` and put this in your `.rsmlbox`:

```
.rsmlbox
{
position:absolute;
top:8px;
left:700px;
margin-right:20%;
width:27.5%;
margin-bottom:80px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use float without breaking your layout by wrapping your code in a container.

CSS

```
.clearfix {
    position:relative;  
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: "&nbsp;";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="lsmlbox">
<div class="boxheader">Meet the Owner</div>
<div class="boxcontent">
SDFSDFSDFSF
</div></div>

<div class="rsmlbox">
<div class="boxheader">Your Best Source Since 1977</div>
<div class="boxcontent">
SDFSDFSDFSDF
</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, display-block is the better way to go. Float was originally intended for images.
[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gFqH/) that demonstrates using inline-block

I have added a class name of box for the two boxes, and changed their current class names to ID's instead:

```
.box{display:inline-block;}
#lsmlbox{}
#rsmlbox{}
```

By using one class name for the two boxes will help reduce the need to write duplicate rules.

Another thing you may want to do, is change the inner `<div>'s` to paragraphs instead. You could then define a standard rule for them using the following css:

```
.box p{padding:10px;color:#333;etc....}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gFqH/5/) demonstrating that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, my problem now is that I am trying to separate the two divs down the center but want it to line up with the other boxes on the page.  I'm using this in my style sheet:
body
{
font-family:arial;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
text-align:center;
}

It lines up everything down the center of my page.  Previously with the floats things lined up properly because the 20% width was based on the proximity to the edge of the screen, but now the two divs are sticking together down the center.

Comment: ok that's a lil tricky, but what you can do is create a container for the boxes, and set the left or right margin for each box to create the gap. you just have to be careful with the widths of the container and the boxes. take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/6gFqH/8/

Comment: can I get contact info?  would be awesome to have you as a resource

Comment: My problem now is that there seems to be some automatic margin being placed. I have to put margin:-2%; on .lsmlbox and .rsmlbox in order for it to line up directly on the container div edges. I would like it to line up so that I can easily line things up with the rest of the page.  I don't understand where the few pixel padding or margin or whatever it is is coming from.  I tried everything to find the culprit but maybe it is just inherent that divs inside of divs cannot line up directly on edges???  In other words... TL;DR How do I line up nested divs so there is no white space?

Comment: Also I want the outer sides of .lsmlbox and .rsmlbox to be sticky.  When changing the size of the window I only want the inside margin to change width.

Comment: the white space issue may be due to the markup. try changing your closing and opening div tags to be on the same line for each box. </div><div class="box">... Ive created a new codepen - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/xDeky update it so that it looks like what you currently have, so i can get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://codepen.io/jeremysfilms/pen/EkeGt
Read my edited OP question above.  I can't get things to line up properly, and when I resize it messes it up anyway.  I want the dotted lines to line up.

Comment: ok what you're trying to do is a bit of a mess! I understand you want to use relative widths because then when the screen is resized it all resizes, but that causes a bit of a headache. best thing for this case is probably to use absolute positioning and media queries. media queries will adjust your values based on screen size. check the code here - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/yrkIq resize the display window and see what happens

Comment: you should be able to get it working on most if not all the modern browser versions. Media queries are exactly what you need for different device support. Generally I try to only define one media query for devices smaller than 640px, but you can be as specific as you like. Here's a blog article on media queries if you're interested - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/